# Why last two box of table shows undefined? I am trying to show values of arrays in tables

Tags: javascript, loops, html-table

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var users = [];
    var aloted = [];
    var allocatedTime;
    var start = [];

    // split function to split the input where space or enter appers.


    var split = function() {
        var test = document.getElementById("allo").value;
        var strin = test.split(/ |\n/);


        //to add odd values in aloted and even values in users.

        for (var i = 0; i <= strin.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                users.push(strin[i]);
            } else {
                aloted.push(strin[i]);
            }
        }


        //creating table.According to me problem is here.

        col1();

        function col1() {

            for (i = 0; i <= users.length; i++) {

                var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                var row = table.insertRow(i);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                cell1.innerHTML = users[i];
                cell2.innerHTML = aloted[i];
            }
        }


    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you fix the formatting?

Comment: Your issue is that `i <= strin.length` should be `i < strin.length`. You're going one beyond the last index in the array. Same with the `i <= users.length`